# Internet Explorer is opening when redirecting to my browser

Tags: java, c++

I have a problem. I have created WebBrowser in C++. I am opening the site (for Example: http://google.com) and click to the link it's opening an Internet bRowser with that uri but I want to open the link  in the my program. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the default program to access the web content. To do so, do following:
`Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs`
Here set your provide your program(.EXE) path for appropriate content type.

Comment: Have you got any code?